# Emgu cv covent color from hsv to bgr

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, emgucv

I have HSV type color and I want to convert it to BGR .It's not an image just an HSV object ?

```
Hsv s = new Hsv((double)Hue, (double)Sat, (double)val);

//this is my HSV color object I need to convert it to BGR color object
```

Answer (score 0):

These is no direct function to convert from HSV to BGR but thankfully writing on is not that terribly hard. The function will be something like this.

```
public static Color ColorFromHSV(double hue, double saturation, double value)
{
    int hi = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(hue / 60)) % 6;
    double f = hue / 60 - Math.Floor(hue / 60);

    value = value * 255;
    int v = Convert.ToInt32(value);
    int p = Convert.ToInt32(value * (1 - saturation));
    int q = Convert.ToInt32(value * (1 - f * saturation));
    int t = Convert.ToInt32(value * (1 - (1 - f) * saturation));

    if (hi == 0)
        return Color.FromArgb(255, v, t, p);
    else if (hi == 1)
        return Color.FromArgb(255, q, v, p);
    else if (hi == 2)
        return Color.FromArgb(255, p, v, t);
    else if (hi == 3)
        return Color.FromArgb(255, p, q, v);
    else if (hi == 4)
        return Color.FromArgb(255, t, p, v);
    else
        return Color.FromArgb(255, v, p, q);
}
```

its using the algorithm mentioned on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV).

Alternately there is also another good code sample here to do the same job.